# Cannot Login to Django Admin Site

Tags: python, django, web-applications

I am trying to create a simple application using Django in Pycharm. I'm using Python 3.7 and Django 3.0.3.
I was following this simple guide on [Jetbrains](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-and-running-your-first-django-project.html#). But for some reason I keep getting the error saying that my username or password is incorrect, whereas they are actually correct. I checked my database, and django_session table is there. I can see the user I have created in auth_user table with is_staff, is_superuser and is_active all true. 
I also tried changing the password after creating a super user as this was the accepted answer on a similar question but that didn't work. 
Here is my settings.py file

```
"""
Django settings for SampleApplication project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.0.3.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'some-secret-key'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'Gym.apps.GymConfig',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'SampleApplication.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]
        ,
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'SampleApplication.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        # MySQL database host ip.
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        # port number.
        'PORT': '3306',
        # database name.
        'NAME': 'sample_database',
        # user name.
        'USER': 'mihir',
        # password
        'PASSWORD': 'Football9#',
        # connect options
        'OPTIONS': {'init_command': "SET sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES'"}
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

urls.py file

```
"""SampleApplication URL Configuration

The `urlpatterns` list routes URLs to views. For more information please see:
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/urls/
Examples:
Function views
    1. Add an import:  from my_app import views
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', views.home, name='home')
Class-based views
    1. Add an import:  from other_app.views import Home
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', Home.as_view(), name='home')
Including another URLconf
    1. Import the include() function: from django.urls import include, path
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('blog/', include('blog.urls'))
"""
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

and my admin.py file

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Sports, Area, Equipment
admin.site.register(Sports)
admin.site.register(Area)
admin.site.register(Equipment)
```

UPDATE:

I just restarted my laptop and it worked, just like that!!

Comment: How are you initializing the admin user via `python manage.py`?

Comment: using createsuperuser command

Answer (score 1):

Is your admin user initialized correctly? Try running

```
python manage.py createsuperuser
```

Comment: I am creating the user with createsuperuser command from the manage.py console. Even after trying this from command line as you said, Im getting the same error